# Правильное добавление в Dictionary

Tags: c#

Есть Dictionary :

```
public Dictionary<int, OrderModel> x = new Dictionary<int, OrderModel>();
```

Есть OrderModel :

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderStatusId { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DishModel> Dishes { get; set; }
}
```

У пользователя есть список товаров. Модель вот:

```
public class DishModel
{
    public int ProvisionerId {get;set;}
}
```

У каждого товара есть свой button.

По нажатию на этот button происходит следующее :

```
 //OrderModel этого товара отправляется в Dictionary, где происходит проверка
 public void method(DishModel dishModel){
  //Если элемент Dictionary по ключу dishModel.ProvisionerId не пустой, то засунь в него элемент типа OrderModel)
 if (x.TryGetValue(dishModel.ProvisionerId, out OrderModel checkForNull))
    {
      beforSerializeForProvisioners[dishModel.ProvisionerId] = OrderModel;
    }
  //Иначе если элемента Dictionary с таким ключом нет, то создай его.
 else
    {
   beforSerializeForProvisioners.Add(dishModel.ProvisionerId, OrderModel);
    }
}
```

В чем моя проблема :

Каждый товар имеет своего поставщика.

Поставщиков n-количество.

Получить это количество можно.

И нужно сделать так :

```
 Если товар имеет поставщика 1, то пусть он сохранится в Dictionary с ключом 1

 Иначе если товар имеет поставщика 2, то пусть он сохранится в Dictionary с ключом 2
 ...и т.д.
```

Но проблема такая :

```
 Когда пользователь нажал на товар, допустим с поставщиком 1, то он успешно создал Dictionary[1] и дал этому ключу значение.
 Если ещё нажать на ещё один товар этого же поставщика, то всё успешно повторится.

 Но если нажать на товар от другого поставщика, то происходит какая-то магия.
Он в Dictionary[1] добавляет этот товар от другого поставщика.
Он создает Dictionary[2] и туда также добавляет этот товар.
```

Решений было 2.

```
1. Как-то правильно организовать добавление. Но у меня MVVM-паттерн, так что придется слишком многое выкладывать и адаптировать, чтобы была соблюдена конфиденциальность.
2. Перебрать весь Dictionary и его значения.
```

Склоняюсь больше ко второму варианту.

Следовательно, нужно сделать так :

```
Provisioners x = new Provisioners();
for(int i=0;i<x.Count();i++){
  foreach(DishModel y in Dictionary[x[i]]){
   if(y.ProvisionerId != Dictionary[x[i]].Dishes.ToList()[0].ProvisionerId) 
   {
      Dictionary[x[i]].Dishes.Remove(y);
    }
}
```

Но когда происходит Remove();

VisualStudio2017 ругается, что массив Dictionary.Dishes был модифицирован и работа foreach прекращена.

Я понимаю почему она прекращена. Но как лучше удалить элементы с другим поставщиком?

Ключом в Dictionary является Id поставщика.

Comment: Упрощенная инициализация следующего:

Comment: Если в x[i] пусто

Comment: @Igot - это значит "если в x[i] пусто"

Comment: Автор, ты в одном случае используешь x, в другом beforSerializeForProvisioners. Проверяешь всегда по x, помещаешь всегда в beforSerializeForProvisioners. Что за дичь?

Comment: `Но если нажать на товар от другого поставщика, то происходит какая-то магия` - эта магия называется ссылки и передача параметра как `out checkForNull`, который затирает предыдущее значение. Итого вы имеете две ссылки на одно и то же значение в словаре: одно затертое `out`'ом значение в `Dictionary[1]` и одно свежедобавленное в `Dictionary[2]`. Ничего удивительного, хоть вы и привели в примере некомпилируемый недокод.

Comment: @AlexKrass как лучше без out проверить?

Comment: Достаточно сделать `checkForNull` локальной переменной, а не глобальной как сейчас. Тогда она будет создана заново и не связана с предыдущим значением при новом вызове метода `method`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отвечая на заданный вопрос: ты можешь либо перейти к [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx), который позволяет одновременно итерироваться по коллекции и модифицировать её (но для однопоточного кода это костыль, рожденный путём наименьшего сопротивления).

Либо ты должен скопировать ключи одного словаря во временный массив вызвав `dic.Keys.ToArray()`, и в цикле бежать по этому массиву, извлекая и удаляя элементы из основного Dictionary по известным ключам.

Но вместо того, чтобы подпирать код костылями, стоит разобраться - почему у тебя элементы попадают в чужой Dictionary.